# How to run a promise the correct way

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I am not sure I am doing this correct. I have a series of responses based off of certain variables set. I want to run a promise so after they have finished the app runs the next line of code. here is my code:

```
const promises = []

if (this.score >= this.scoreNeeded) {
  this.correct = true
  this.retrieveCode(this.clueorder)
  this.feedback = 'Congrats you are moving on. Here is your next code '
} else {
  console.log('1')
  if (locimgface && !this.smile) {
    this.feedback += 'You need to smile in your picture. '
  }
  if (locimgfacesurprise && !this.surprise) {
    this.feedback += 'You need to look very surprised in your picture. '
  }
  if (locimgfacesorrow && !this.sorrow) {
    this.feedback += 'You need to look really sad in your picture. '
  }
  if (locationimagetexton && !this.atLocation) {
    this.feedback += 'We could not find the text in the image. It needs to have one of these words "' + locationimagetextwithspaces + '" somewhere in the picture. '
  }
  if (locationimagelabelon && !this.foundItem) {
    this.feedback += 'We could not find the item in the image. It needs to have one of these items "' + locationimagelabelswithspaces + '" somewhere in the picture. '
  }

  promises.push(this.feedback)

  Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    console.log('completed from promise');
    this.deleteImage(this.fullPath)
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(`ERROR: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
  })
}
```

What I am trying to do is make sure all the feedback messages are set properly and then run the deleteImage function, in addition in the block of code for a good score I would like to wait for a response from retrieveCode before posting the feedback.

As always any and all help is much appreciated.

UPDATE:

I might be doing it wrong but there are multiple triggers.

If the code is missing one or many it needs to let the user know what is missing, i.e. if the program is looking for a smile, and some text and a picture is submitted with the text but no smile the user should get a feedback msg letting them know they need to smile in the picture.

If the program is looking for a surprised look, text and and a label and the user submits a pic with both a surprised look and the text they will get a feedback msg letting them know they need to include the label.

If the program is looking for a smile, text and a label ('car') and the user submits a picture with none of these they will get a feedback msg saying they need to smile, they need to provide the missing text and they need to have a car in the picture.

For each item missing the user is provided specific feedback to help them along.

The end goal is to build the feedback message then run the next function. either deleteImage() or retrieveCode() depending on the user's score

UPDATE 2

here is the deleteImage function

```
deleteImage (fullPath) {
        console.log('2')
        let storage = firebase.storage();
        let storageRef = storage.ref();

        // Create a reference to the file we want to delete
        let imageRef = storageRef.child(fullPath);
        imageRef.delete().then(() => {
            console.log('3')
            this.reset()
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(`file delete error occurred: ${error}`)
        })
    },
```

UPDATE 3:

Here is the retrieveCode() function.

```
retrieveCode(clueorder) {
    // get the next clue by adding 1 to this clue
    const newclue = this.getNextClue(clueorder)

    this.$store.dispatch('retrieveCode', {
        newclue: newclue,
        oldclue: clueorder
    });
}
```

Comment: `this.feedback` doesn't seem to be a `Promise`, it's a `string` in your example, thus, your `promises` array is an array of `strings`.

Comment: Can whoever downgraded my question explain why. It does users no good to be downgraded without a reason

Comment: @steadweb thank you for your feedback. Can you show me how to handle this properly?

Comment: I didn't downgrade either :) I just pointed out that `this.feedback` aren't promises

Comment: @steadweb that downgrade comment was not meant for you, I just happened to post it right after you :)

Comment: sure - I'll provide an example of how `promises` and `Promise.all` works

Comment: @steadweb much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) page:

> The Promise.all() method returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises passed as an iterable have resolved or when the iterable contains no promises.

#### Basic Example

Let's create a really basic function that returns a `Promise` (using `Promise.resolve`), which returns the string which you pass it.

```js
// You could use new Promise(resolve => resolve(str));
const fetchData = str => Promise.resolve(str)

// Array of promises to wait on
const data = [
    fetchData('foo'),
    fetchData('bar'),
    fetchData('baz')
];

Promise.all(data).then(responses => {
    console.log(responses);
});
```

You don't have to return `Promises` either, you could simply pass an array of strings and `Promise.all` would "resolve" those.

```js
// You could use new Promise(resolve => resolve(str));
const fetchData = str => str

// Array of promises to wait on
const data = [
    fetchData('foo'),
    fetchData('bar'),
    fetchData('baz')
];

Promise.all(data).then(responses => {
    console.log(responses);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I apologize but I am not sure how to incorporate this into my code. Any chance you can show this within my code above?

Comment: With your example, what are you trying to achieve? As you're concatinating `this.feedback` (as it's a string) which isn't really async :) - let me know and I'll provide an example with your code.

Comment: You bet, I updated the question to add in what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: BTW: maybe since I am concatenating I don't need to use a promise. I am not sure.

Comment: Oh ya, my desire is after the feedback string is created then the next function i.e. deleteImage() or retrieveCode() runs

Comment: Thanks - are the `retrieveCode` and `deleteImage` functions async? (do they return promises)?

Comment: retrieveCode no, deleteImage yes. I have added deleteImage to my question above

Comment: Your `deleteImage` uses `.then` but doesn't return a promise :) it's async for sure, but if you want to do something off the back of that function, you could return a promise. I can provide examples in my answer.

Comment: I also just posted the retrieveCode() function. I am using Vue.js and Vuex.

Comment: I have a watch on the store so when retrieveCode fires and the getter in the store changes the watch picks it up and displays the new code to the user